# Display menu items depending on user roles defined in web.xml

Tags: jsf, authentication, web.xml, conditional-rendering, security-constraint

I have my own realm classes extends AppservPasswordLoginModule and AppservRealm where I get user and roles from my own table in database. In web.xml I defined access to pages and it works.
I have some mechanism to read main menu from my menu.xml file in my bean with @SessionScoped annotation. 
 I want to use rules from web.xml to display only this items, which user has acces to (defined in web.xml), without repeating configuration in my menu.xml file.
I imagine that the solution might be to check the access to the page when I create menu item for this page in my SessionScoped bean, but I don't know how it could be checked easily.
 What is the best solution for this situation? 
 I'm using glassfish 4.1 and jsf 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by the following method:

In my ServletListener

```
@WebListener
public class implements ServletListener ServletContextListener {...}
```

I read  security-constraint from web.xml, parsing them and store it in my @ApplicationScoped bean.

In @SessionScoped bean, in @PostConstruct annotated method I get all roles stored in @ApplicationScoped bean and checked each individual by

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().GetExternalContext().IsUserInRole(role);
```

method.

So I have all current user roles. Then, in my @SessionScoped bean,  for each menu item I check whether the resource represented by the url of this menu item is available for roles that current user has.

EDIT: The bad side of this solution is that I analyzing the web.xml file only, without annotations